# Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment] (trying to use EntityManager)

Tags: mysql, maven, jpa, intellij-idea, wildfly

Hi, I'm in the middle of creating my first serious web-app using javaee, JPA/Hibernate, MySQL, Maven and IntelliJ. When I was using SessionFactory everything was ok but I decided to use Entitymanager instead - and I spent the whole day fixing bugs but I can't fix this one:

There is an error when I'm trying to add new row to database through my webapp:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to build entity manager factory
org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:66)
javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
domain.CarDAO.<init>(CarDAO.java:8)
controller.CarToDbServlet.doPost(CarToDbServlet.java:17)
```

and additionally from IntelliJ console:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]

Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling DriverManager#getConnection

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/carent?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
```

This is my CarDAO class:

```
public class CarDAO {

    private EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("JPAPersistUnit");

    private List<Car> carList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addCar(Car car) {
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction trans = em.getTransaction();

        try {
            trans.begin();
            em.persist(car);
            trans.commit();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            if(trans != null) {trans.rollback();}
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }
```

This is a persistence.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd" version="2.1">

    <persistence-unit name="JPAPersistUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>domain.Car</class>
        <class>domain.Customer</class>
        <class>domain.Orders</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.Driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/carent?useSSL=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root"/>

            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

These are my dependencies in pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.12.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

I was looking for a solution here, I found a few similar topics but according to them it seems that everything is ok with my code. Maybe this is a problem with IntelliJ? But I added a datasource which is connecting with my db without problems...
When I delete the provided scope in hibernate-core and hibernate-jpa I get this error:

> org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory

Is it something with wildfly?

Please help :(

Comment: It looks like you've included a library that has `org.dom4j.DocumentFactory` in your deployment. I'd also suggest using a container managed `EntityManager` rather than creating one manually.

Answer (score 0):

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for
>   jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/carent?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC

This exception caused by missing jdbc driver or jdbc driver url does not match the jdbc driver. SO eerify javax.persistence.jdbc.url and included the driver jar to classpath.

**Update:**
Default dependency scope is **compile**. This scope means that you need the JAR for compiling and running the application.

**Provided** means that you need the JAR for compiling, but at run time application expect container or jdk to provide the dependencies. So these artifacts don't need it packaged within application.

Refer to [maven dependency scope documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) to check transitive dependencies scope. Can be verify the dependencies scope through dependency tree.

```
mvn dependency:tree

[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.2.12.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.20.0-GA:provided
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.1.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.3.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:provided
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Final:provided
```

In your case issue with dom4j library. You need to determine where that is coming from and ensure and set required scope and transitive dependencies can be excluded.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.12.Final</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: But I think I checked everything and when I test connection to DB via IntelliJ everything is ok. I have all required dependecies and connection with SessionFactory was also ok... When I delete scope-provided from this dependencies I get an error from dom4j (as I mentioned at the end of my message)... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
Some of dependencies are provided by wildfly so I had to use *dependencyManagement* tag with org.jboss.spec - jboss-javaee-7.0 dependency and set some of my dependencies as provided (i.a. hibernate).
And what's even more important - I started using dependency injections instead of creating new objects (from DAO's) with *new* word in my servlets.

But thanks for answers!